# highcharts with ZendFramework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, highcharts

I have a problem with HighCharts :

If I include on my header:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery.min.js') ?> 
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/highcharts.js') ?>
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/exporting.js')  ?>
```

I have an error:

> TypeError: ha is not a function

AND

> TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

But I don't understand because if I include normaly with:

```
<script>src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

I have no problems...

Comment: Files: jquery.min.js, highcharts.js and exporting.js have to be present in the public/js directory. Check also if they have suitable permissions.

Comment: I think your jQuery file has something to do with this. Check the path for it and the version. Also check version of Highcharts the $().highcharts() was introduced recently.

Comment: I have Jquery,highcharts and exporting in /public/js and all users can modified or writed on file.

Comment: Check your links of jquery, highcharts and exporting in your browser. Whether it's working or not?

Comment: Also check if the order of the included files are correct First jquery.min.js and then highcharts.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `$this->baseUrl().` before js like this:

```
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery.min.js');
```

And you should do it with only one instruction and add `;` at the end of onstructions.

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery.min.js')
                              ->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/highcharts.js')
                              ->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/exporting.js');
```

Comment: Sorry for the time of my answer, your solution operate , thks for your help. I have a question , What "baseUrl()" do it?

Comment: Great, happy for you. please validate this answer. :) For baseUrl, you can see the [documentation](baseUrl(baseUrl(http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) :)